# Keep input focused after clearing it's value

Tags: javascript, html, input, focus

When I clear input `input.value = '';` the input field loses focus. Is there a way to clear it and keep focus on it so the user can keep typing?

Comment: Are you sure that it is losing focus?  Or that it isn't losing it for another reason?  I cleared the value in Javascript of an element right now in the console and `document.activeElement` still showed it as having focus... if nothing else, you could probably just refocus it w/ Javascript immediately after clearing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.focus();
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById("txt");
function clicked(){
  input.value = '';
  input.focus();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" />

<button onclick="clicked()"> Clear </button>
```